# Is it possible to get Thailand visa in embassy in Malaysia or Cambodia without airline tickets or personal vehicle?

Tags: visas, bookings, thailand, southeast-asia, overland

I'm travelling in Southeast Asia and going to apply for tourist visa in Thai embassy in Malaysia or Cambodia. I'm going to travel by bus, train, or maybe bus/train + cross the border by foot. [Visa application checklist](http://www.thaiembassy.org/kualalumpur/contents/files/services-20170329-105808-985625.pdf) says I need

> A Copy of reservation/confirmation of return ticket (ticket in and out of Thailand)

I'm not sure if overland tickets will be good for this (esp. if it's tickets to/from the border). Does anyone have experience with bus or train tickets or no tickets at all? Maybe overland ticket to Thailand and plane ticket out of Thailand?

Note that I know it's possible to book a ticket for 24 hours without paying. But it means some amount of risk and also it's a lie (I'm not going to buy those tickets) which I'd like to avoid.

Extra note (if relevant): it's not a visa run, I've never been to Thailand before.

Comment: Why not use a throwaway ticket?

Comment: @JonathanReez this is an option. But I'd prefer use the real overland ticket if it's possible.

Comment: How many TVs do you already have to thailand in the same passport?  How often have you been to Thailand before in the last 24 months?

Comment: @JonGrah I've never been to Thailand (mentioned this in the bottom).

Comment: forgot to ask that other question:  what country is your passport from?

Comment: @JonGrah Ukraine (1 person) + U.S. (another person)

Comment: Should be no problems for either passport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Thai MFA regulation technically says](http://www.mfa.go.th/main/en/services/4908/15398-Issuance-of-Visa.html) POOT must be an air ticket (`Evidence of travel from Thailand (`**`air ticket`**`paid in full)` ).  You could try other forms of POOT.

ThaiEmbassy.org is **not an official site**, despite their obvious attempt to make it appear so.

BTW if you are passing through Malaysia, Penang would be the better Thai Consulate overall for just about any visa (unless you want to go to Kota Bharu).  Not sure if [they are still asking for air POOT](https://www.thaivisa.com/forum/topic/968520-proof-of-onward-travel-for-all-visa-types-at-penang-starting-tomorrow/?do=findComment&comment=11616989).  Again, you can present your [land/boat] POOT and if needed, just get an air POOT to a neighbor country.  Cambodia (Phnom Penh) is similar.   Especially if you use an agent, then a few extra $$ might make application process smoother.  KL Thai Embassy is more of a hit/miss with emphasis on miss if you are not a Malaysian resident.